# How would i be able to round the outputs to an integer?

Tags: javascript, rounding, calculator

I need to make these outputs produce an integer rather than decimals

```
 {
    outputs[0].textContent = value / 0.7;
    outputs[1].textContent = value * 1;
    outputs[2].textContent = value / 0.7 - (value / 0.7 /  100*40);
    outputs[3].textContent = value * 1;
    outputs[4].textContent = value / 0.7 - (value / 0.7 /  100*20);
    outputs[5].textContent = value / 0.7 - (value / 0.7 /  100*10);
  }
```

Comment: `parseInt` or `toFixed`

Comment: [Math.round](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Math.round()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round):

> The `Math.round()` function returns the value of a number rounded to the nearest integer.

```
outputs[0].textContent = Math.round(value / 0.7);
.....
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 {
  outputs[0].textContent = Math.round(value);
  outputs[1].textContent = Math.round(value);
  outputs[2].textContent = Math.round(value);
  outputs[3].textContent = Math.round(value);
  outputs[4].textContent = Math.round(value);
  outputs[5].textContent = Math.round(value);
}
```